# ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor Maven error

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss, repository

I am using the latest Eclipse for Java EE with JBoss Tools installed so Maven is included. I imported an existing Maven project to my workspace and tried to update the dependencies but I only get errors error in my POM that some argument is invalid and no artifact could have been transfered.
There are actually two different errors and maybe they depend on each other?
You can check: the server is available and I also tried to reinstall Eclipse and JBoss. So what else is missing?

> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   edu.kit.aifb.ai2.sqsclient:sqsclient:jar:1.0.0:
>   ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer
>   edu.kit.aifb.ai2.sqsclient:sqsclient:pom:1.0.0 from
>   http://eorg-ai2.aifb.kit.edu:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases
>   was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of Beehive has elapsed or updates are
>   forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact
>   edu.kit.aifb.ai2.sqsclient:sqsclient:pom:1.0.0 from/to Beehive
>   (http://eorg-ai2.aifb.kit.edu:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases):
>   Invalid argument: getsockname to
>   http://eorg-ai2.aifb.kit.edu:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/edu/kit/aifb/ai2/sqsclient/sqsclient/1.0.0/sqsclient-1.0.0.pom

There is indeed nothing in my repository-folder but .pom.lastUpdated-files

> Error resolving version for plugin
>   'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin' from the repositories
>   [local (C:\Users\Gregor.Gregs.m2\repository), central
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin
>   repository

Thank you

Comment: Is the nexus server running fine and proxying central and other repositories?  If so, could you retry after deleing .pom.lastUpdated files?

Comment: Yes, the server is fine as well as the whole project - it works for others. I also took their repository and pasted it into my folder and I got the project running. So Maven should be fine to.
Could it be that there is a problem with my PC's name as there is a dot in it? Just saw that in the error report of the second error there is a backslash missing. But as there are .pom.lastUpdated files it shouldn't matter..?

(I also had them deleted, the .pom.lastUpdated files as well as my cache)

Answer (score 19):

For me it was because Eclipse was caching the exception ( even after I solved the original problem )  so try to:

```
right click on project -> maven -> update-project -> force to update snapshot/release -> OK.
```

it worked for me for a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check in you eclipse that settings file path is pointing to right one.
Window --> Preferences --> Maven--> User Settings.

Answer (score 1):

right click on project -> maven -> update-project -> force to update snapshot/release -> OK.

it worked for me too